# Python / Import and design of program

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I’m looking for solution for designing my program.

My program consists of 3 blocks:

- Classes
- Functions
- Other utilities

I want to structure my program this way:

```
program_folder/
   main.py
   classes_folder/
       class_1.py
       class_2.py
   functions_folder/
       set_of_func_1.py
       set_of_func_1.py
   utilities_folder/
       set_of_utilities_1.py
       set_of_utilities_1.py
```

I want to:

- any scripts in «classes_folder» were able to import any of scripts in
  «functions_folder».
- any scripts in «functions_folder» were able
  to import any of scripts in «utilities_folder».
- all scripts were
  normally used by main.py.
- all scripts in «classes_folder»,
  «functions_folder» and «utilities_folder» could be tested when worked
  as «main» (`if __name__ == “__main__”:` some tests)
- «program_folder»
  could be in any place in my computer (there shouldn’t be dependency
  on exact path to «program_folder»).

From all the above I thought I have to:

- Change import search path for all scripts in «classes_folder»,
  «functions_folder» and «utilities_folder».
- Set current working
  directory to «program_folder» for all scripts?

Is there a way I can do it?
Does my idea look good or have I put there some unexpected problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a skeleton project like the following:

```
/path/to/project/
  setup.py
  my_project/
    __init__.py
    a/
      __init__.py
    b/
      __init__.py

==> ./my_project/__init__.py <==
print('my_project/__init__.py')

==> ./my_project/a/__init__.py <==
import my_project
print('my_project/a/__init__.py')

==> ./my_project/b/__init__.py <==
import my_project.a
print('my_project/b/__init__.py')

==> ./setup.py <==
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='my_project',
      version='1.0',
      description='my_project',
      author='author',
      packages=['my_project'])
```

Then you can install the project locally using `pip install -e /path/to/project/` (the project folder is not copied, just gets registered; there's a dependency on the exact path, but this dependency is not hard-coded in project files themselves).

As the result, `import my_project`, `import my_project.a` etc. do that they mean:

```
$ python my_project/b/__init__.py 
my_project/__init__.py
my_project/a/__init__.py
my_project/b/__init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

A common Python project structure could look like this:

```
project_name/
  setup.py
  requirements.txt  

  project_name/
    __main__.py

    classes/
      __init__.py
      class1.py
      class2.py

    functions/
      __init__.py
      functions.py

    utils/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
```

Then, you could modify your imports from absolute to relative and run your package using something like:

```
$ /path/to/project_name> python -m project_name
```

Note that `setup.py` is only required if you want to install your package under some of your interpreters.

> **Note**: see comments below also

Comment: How is it common to split classes and functions into separate folders? And how would functions differ from utils, which seem to warrant their own folder?

Comment: To be clear, it is common to have such _layout_, not to split utils, funcs, classes, etc. into their own folders. Just copied author's naming to make the idea more clear. One can put whatever is required into subfolders, depending on their taste and project's logical structure.